# MySQL cursor rename tables, script error

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL, and I have a script that is supposed to rename all tables to uppercase. I have an error in it , but I can't figure out why it is not working. Any help is appreciated!

```
DECLARE a VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT DISTINCT table_name 
    FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_schema='admin27_shop';

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;

OPEN cur1;

read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO a;
    IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

    CREATE TABLE CONCAT(a, '1') SELECT * FROM a;
    DROP TABLE a;
    RENAME TABLE CONCAT(a, '1') TO UPPER(a);
END LOOP;

CLOSE cur1;
```

UPDATE: The error message happens on line 1, at the declaration of the variable, says that there is a syntax error...

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your SQL error message.

Comment: I'd have some real concerns about this script. The `CREATE TABLE/DROP TABLE` as written is going to lose all of your existing indexes, etc. My gut instinct is that your error occurs trying to drop a parent table with a foreign key relationship to a child table that still exists.

Comment: I am not really worrying about the indexes at this point, I have that Windows/Unix upper-lower case bug and I am trying to find a remedy without having to go into the actual script to edit each individual table definiton one at a time. Thanks for your concerns though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must be my specific version of MySQL and the application. Closing this question.